# Reduce multiple queries for reporting

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a query for a sales report, the code I have works excellent in the aspect that it returns the correct result, however I think it can be greatly improved since I am using multiple queries to generate the columns "Total_Productos", "Total_Servicios " and "Total", I have tried some ways to adjust it but I would like to hear some advice, I attach the code and the result it shows

```
SELECT f.numero, f.fecha, CONCAT(c.nombre, ' ', c.apellido) AS Cliente, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(' x', CONVERT(fp2.cantidad, CHAR(10)), ' ', nombre) AS Product
    FROM facturas_productos fp2
    INNER JOIN productos ON productos.codigo = fp2.productos_codigo 
    WHERE fp2.facturas_numero = fp.facturas_numero) AS Productos,
    
    TRUNCATE((SELECT SUM(fp2.cantidad * productos.precio_venta) AS T_Producto
    FROM facturas_productos fp2
    INNER JOIN productos ON productos.codigo = fp2.productos_codigo 
    WHERE fp2.facturas_numero = fp.facturas_numero), 2) AS Total_Productos,
    
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' x', CONVERT(fs2.cantidad, CHAR(10)), ' ', nombre))
    FROM facturas_servicios fs2
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.codigo = fs2.servicios_codigo 
    WHERE fs2.facturas_numero = fs.facturas_numero) AS Servicios,
    
    TRUNCATE((SELECT SUM(fs2.cantidad * servicios.precio) AS T_Servicio
    FROM facturas_servicios fs2
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.codigo = fs2.servicios_codigo 
    WHERE fs2.facturas_numero = fs.facturas_numero), 2) AS Total_Servicios,
    
    TRUNCATE((SELECT SUM(fs2.cantidad * servicios.precio) AS T_Servicio
    FROM facturas_servicios fs2
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.codigo = fs2.servicios_codigo 
    WHERE fs2.facturas_numero = fs.facturas_numero) + 
    (SELECT SUM(fp2.cantidad * productos.precio_venta) AS T_Producto
    FROM facturas_productos fp2
    INNER JOIN productos ON productos.codigo = fp2.productos_codigo 
    WHERE fp2.facturas_numero = fp.facturas_numero), 2) AS Total
    
FROM facturas f 
INNER JOIN clientes c ON c.ID = f.clientes_ID
INNER JOIN facturas_productos fp ON fp.facturas_numero = f.numero
INNER JOIN facturas_servicios fs ON fs.facturas_numero = f.numero
WHERE f.fecha BETWEEN "2023-01-01" AND "2023-02-04"
GROUP BY f.numero, fp.facturas_numero, fs.facturas_numero, f.fecha, c.nombre, c.apellido
ORDER BY f.numero ASC;
```

Result from the query above:
[image: Result from the query above]

I tried to take from the previous queries the values to calculate the total, however it gave me another unexpected result (generated an error/wrong value), i.e:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' x', CONVERT(fs2.cantidad, CHAR(10)), ' ', nombre)), fs2.cantidad * servicios.precio AS Monto
    FROM facturas_servicios fs2
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.codigo = fs2.servicios_codigo 
    WHERE fs2.facturas_numero = fs.facturas_numero) AS Servicios
```

generates: *Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)*

**More info:** *I created the database from a diagram using forward engineer and not from scripts (still learning at university)*
[Database EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug3Qy.png)

Comment: Please don't use images for sample data or data structures. Add full `CREATE TABLE` statements in code blocks, so we can easily recreate your example. Add sample data as `INSERT` statements and/or markdown tables. You are currently storing monetary values in floats. These should be changed to decimal columns.

Comment: Are there no INDEXes?  Not even `PRIMARY KEYs`?  Please provide the `CREATEs` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: It is unclear whether `CONVERT()` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL >= 8.0.14, you can move your correlated sub-queries to [lateral derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) -

```
SELECT f.numero, f.fecha, CONCAT(c.nombre, ' ', c.apellido) AS Cliente, 
    fp.Productos, fp.Total_Productos,
    fs.Servicios, fs.Total_Servicios,
    IFNULL(fs.Total_Servicios, 0) + IFNULL(fp.Total_Productos, 0) AS Total
FROM facturas f
INNER JOIN clientes c ON c.ID = f.clientes_ID
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT('x', fp2.cantidad, ' ', nombre SEPARATOR ', ') AS Productos,
        SUM(fp2.cantidad * productos.precio_venta) AS Total_Productos
    FROM facturas_productos fp2
    INNER JOIN productos ON productos.codigo = fp2.productos_codigo 
    WHERE fp2.facturas_numero = f.numero
) fp ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT('x', fs2.cantidad, ' ', nombre SEPARATOR ', ') AS Servicios,
        SUM(fs2.cantidad * servicios.precio) AS Total_Servicios
    FROM facturas_servicios fs2
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.codigo = fs2.servicios_codigo 
    WHERE fs2.facturas_numero = f.numero
) fs ON 1 = 1
WHERE f.fecha BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-04'
ORDER BY f.numero ASC;
```

I have changed the joins to `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` as I assume it is possible for an invoice to contain products but not services, and vice versa.

An alternative approach, which does not require MySQL >= 8.0.14, is to aggregate all the products and services in their derived tables, instead of doing the lateral join -

```
SELECT f.numero, f.fecha, CONCAT(c.nombre, ' ', c.apellido) AS Cliente, 
    fp.Productos, fp.Total_Productos,
    fs.Servicios, fs.Total_Servicios,
    IFNULL(fs.Total_Servicios, 0) + IFNULL(fp.Total_Productos, 0) AS Total
FROM facturas f
INNER JOIN clientes c ON c.ID = f.clientes_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        fp.facturas_numero,
        GROUP_CONCAT('x', fp.cantidad, ' ', nombre SEPARATOR ', ') AS Productos,
        SUM(fp.cantidad * productos.precio_venta) AS Total_Productos
    FROM facturas_productos fp
    INNER JOIN productos ON productos.codigo = fp.productos_codigo 
    GROUP BY fp.facturas_numero
) fp ON f.numero = fp.facturas_numero
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        fs.facturas_numero,
        GROUP_CONCAT('x', fs.cantidad, ' ', nombre SEPARATOR ', ') AS Servicios,
        SUM(fs.cantidad * servicios.precio) AS Total_Servicios
    FROM facturas_servicios fs
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.codigo = fs.servicios_codigo 
    GROUP BY fs.facturas_numero
) fs ON f.numero = fs.facturas_numero
WHERE f.fecha BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-04'
ORDER BY f.numero ASC;
```

This may be a little bit faster when retrieving all invoices but will probably be slower when retrieving a small subset of a large number of invoices.

And here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6AFIhN-U)

Comment: I added information about the database to the question and I also tried to run the query that you commented but it says that "Where is not valid at this position, expecting FOR, SELECT, ...." I did some adjustments to make it work but it still showed me the error (PS: I'm reading about LEFT JOIN LATERALS but so far I don't understand much)

Comment: The answer worked perfectly, thank you very much, I exported the db and put all the code in "db-fiddle" in case you wanted to do tests, this is the link: [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRDFSsJkoz3jaaBcyGXX8a/1#&togetherjs=5QzcivROoq)

Comment: Glad it works for you. Is there any measurable performance improvement with your test dataset?

Comment: That's right! When loading the report it is being twice as fast!!